# A Simple Algorithm for Imposing Semi-definite Constraints

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

What is the simplest algorithm to implement, to impose semi-definite constraints?

$\min_{X\succeq 0} f(X) $, where $X$ is an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix, and $f$ is a general smooth convex nonlinear function.

Suppose size of $X$ is small, e.g. $n = 20$.

I myself can name some methods (like interior point methods, etc), but have not experience in implementation, so do not know which one is simpler to start with.

Comment: Do you have a specific $f$ in mind? The best choice would indeed depend on that.

Comment: $v'*\log(1+\exp(-X))*v$ is an example of what I have in mind, where $v$ is a vector.

Comment: Very interesting. I'd say my answer stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say a projected gradient method is likely going to work well for a simple problem like that. That is, alternate between gradient steps
$$X_+ = X - \alpha \nabla f(X)$$
and projection steps:
$$X_{++} = \mathop{\text{arg}\,\text{min}}_{X\succeq 0} \|X-X_+\|_F$$
The projection is relatively simple: given a Schur decomposition $X_+=U\Sigma U^T$, then $X_{++}=U\Sigma_+ U^T$, where $\Sigma_+$ is formed by replacing any negative (diagonal) elements of $\Sigma$ with zero: $(\Sigma_+)_{ii}=\max\{\Sigma_{ii},0\}$.

If $f(X)$ is not strongly convex, you may want to consider an *accelerated* first-order method; search for "Nesterov's optimal gradient" or "Nesterov's accelerated gradient" in your favorite search engine for a start. My Matlab toolbox [TFOCS](http://cvxr.com/tfocs/) might be helpful for you here, but it is by no means necessary.

An interior-point method is OK, and would be good if you need high accuracy. But it can be a bit difficult to assemble the Newton system. Certainly, with a problem of your smaller size, it will be tractable on a PC.

Do you have a specific $f$ in mind?

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer.

Comment: @ Michael C. Grant: How should I proceed if $\Sigma_{ii}$ are all negative at one step?

Comment: The projection would be zero in that case. Do make sure you are choosing your step size $\alpha$ wisely, however. You may be taking steps that are too large. Look up the Armijo Goldstein rule, for instance.

Comment: I had the sign wrong in the gradient step, BTW. Hope you figured that out.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thank you.